# Parsing problems during JSON response using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new using Angularjs and I am having an issue parsing a `JSON` response. I have login credentials like `Username` and `password` and I am trying to parse it , when user clicks on the login `button()`. If the name and password matched in the following server , I should get success message. This is the HTML code I am using:

```
<form ng-submit="loginform()" name="logform"><br/><br>
<tr ng-repeat="logcred in signinfo"></tr>

<div>
 <label form="emailinput"><b>Email</b></label>
 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="uname" id="emailinput" placeholder="you@example.com" ng-model="logcred.username" >
</div>

<div>
  <label form="pwdinput"><b>Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="pwdinput" placeholder="*******" ng-model="logcred.password">
</div>

<a ng-click="reloadPage()" class="navbar-brand" ></a>

<div>
 <button type="cancel" class="btn" ng-click="toggle_cancel()">Cancel</button>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()" >Login</button>
</div>
</form>
```

This is the Javascript code using AngularJS:

```
app.controller('credientials', function($scope,$http) {
$scope.loginform = function (username, password){
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/loginfo')
.then(
    function successCallback(data){
    $scope.response = data;
if($scope.username === 'response.username' && $scope.password === 'response.password'){
    $scope.signinfo = data.loginfo;
}
else{
    console.log("Error");
    }
})
});
```

The HTML is showing the variable $scope.response with the JSON returned by the server, but I don't know how to authentication it properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. After the successCallback(data) gets called, you want to set $scope.username and $scope.password?

Comment: once i got the successCallback , I am trying to match the username and password , which i am getting from the server. If they match , I should be able to login

Comment: In this way you are executing the login authentication on the client. I think this is a bad practice. It's your service on backend (the server) that should authenticate you. If you want to go on like this you should check this: if(data && data.username === username && data.password === password) { console.log("login executed) }

Comment: yes. But I don't know how to parse it using the server ?

Comment: You should execute a  POST on the server, specifying username and password inserted by the user. The server should execute a query on the DB, to check if there are any rows with that name and password. If yes return true, if false return false. then the client should parse this response.

Comment: After that ,how should i call the response in HTML

Comment: I have already executed POST on my server and it's working fine

Comment: So I dont get your problem. ù

Comment: I already have server, where existing user's username and password is stored. I am trying to access those data  to **login** in to my site. If the existing user data is stored in my server, they can login orelse they cannot

Comment: @phoine as suggested by gaetano , you should move your authentication logic on server side. i.e. in your case `/loginfo` in this action. You match username and password in server side instead of sending password/username to client side as $http response. If username /password matches in server side then send success callback to client side and display it in HTML

Comment: I got it @Rahul

Comment: if you have any small working example, can u drop it @Rahul

Comment: @phoine I shall create a fiddle for you...but I dont have working code for serverside. Let me try for it.

Comment: yea sure.. @Rahul

Comment: @phoine http://jsfiddle.net/oymo9g2f/61/ please chk this fiddle and do read comments as well

Comment: @Rahul. Thanks It help me lot.

Comment: @phoine shall I post this as answer then ? accept it if it helps you !

Comment: yea sure go ahead

Comment: @Rahul. I have small dout, where should i apply `if` condition, to match the usercredentials

Comment: you can return a json data back into your client side once you checked the user credentials in the server. If condition should be done inside the server post request. And the passed json data will contain the essential login credentials data you need.

Comment: see the answer below... and **whats your `/loginfo` service does ? and what does it returns exactly** ?
the answer i have posted is the best practice to follow; however if u really want to do it in client side then let me know; i shall edit the answer

Comment: `loginfo` contains the user credentials and it will return username and password @Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Check updated snippet of authentication at client side.

```
if(userData.username == response.data.username && userData.password === response.data.password){
      $scope.signinfo = response.data 
}
```

You will get `userData` variable from form submit button .. see how i am passing 
 username and pasword to controller using `ng-submit="loginform(logcred)"`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('credientials', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.loginform = function(userData) {
    console.log(userData);
    $http.post('https://reqres.in/api/users', userData) // here in post rew i am passing username and password to mock api
      .then(function(response) {
       //as suggested by you in response u will get username = admin@evol.com password = admin;   
        console.log(response)
        if(userData.username == response.data.username && userData.password === response.data.password){
            $scope.signinfo = response.data 
        }
      });
  }
});

//**NOTE** in above HTTP call you use your url `http://localhost:3000/loginfo` and in your serverside get the username from the request and check password for that username in your database. If password matches with what you have entered then send  success message or user details back to client side.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="credientials">
  <form ng-submit="loginform(logcred)" name="logform">
    <br/>
    <br>
   {{signinfo}}

    <div>
      <label form="emailinput"><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="uname" id="emailinput" placeholder="you@example.com" ng-model="logcred.username">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label form="pwdinput"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="pwdinput" placeholder="*******" ng-model="logcred.password">
    </div>

    <a ng-click="reloadPage()" class="navbar-brand"></a>

    <div>
      <button type="cancel" class="btn" ng-click="toggle_cancel()">Cancel</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

in above HTTP call you use your url `http://localhost:3000/loginfo` and in your serverside get the username from the request and check password for that username in your database. If password matches with what you have entered then send  success message or user details back to client side.

**where should i apply if condition, to match the usercredentials?**

You need to check if condition in the server side logic where u fetch data from database. like in your server (i.e. in /loginfo)

```
if(userpassword == passwordfromDB){
  //send success message to client side
}
```

Comment: rahul could you provide some more information. When user enter his name, the data should match with the server data. For that i have `post` request and after that I'm not getting what i am suppose to do

Comment: What are u passing to ur post req ? I mean what data u passing ? And in response of that post req what are u getting in success call back ?

Comment: I am sending `username` ans `password` in post req. In success call back i'm getting `id`

Comment: actually i.m fetching the data from the server. After that when I'm using post to compare the data, i got stuck over there

Comment: Ok.. post ur response in question ...may be sample response ..  I shall give u updated answer

Comment: If possible do it in client side and drop me. I'll go through it . Thanks @Rahul

Comment: username = admin@evol.com password = admin This is the response data . I am fetching this data from server , I should match these responses when use post same credentials input

Comment: just now i saw your updated answer. But my code is not working fine. When the credentials is not getting matched up.

Comment: I am receiving data from post and its skipping  `if` condition and the posted data is getting saved in my server by creating new id

Comment: @phoine what response u getting back from server ? can you post here ?

Comment: yea sure @rahul

Comment: I have created plunker, please look over it. Let me know what mistake i have done

Comment: @phoine what response u getting in line no 17 in this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/EnlVS7PlQsCYiFsWdFcj?p=preview .. i updated this little bit.. just check on console at ur end what response u getting at line 17 by hitting `http://localhost:3000/loginfo` as i dont have your `logininfo` service

Comment: on line 17 . I am getting **user input** details and new object is getting created

Comment: Is it expected  response u getting ? Can you post that log here ?

Comment: no rahul.. Even if the unregistered person login , they can access it. I ll drop a log now

Comment: I have uploaded the log image. Please take a look over it

Comment: I just found the mistake . Actually `if` condition is not working. if (userData.username === response.data.username && userData.password === response.data.password)

Comment: i checked in console. **userData.username and resopnse.data.username** , both are taking the user input details and the condition is not working